# Magento: find orders containing a product

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way in Magento to find all orders that contain a given product? It would be even better if it could be done from the administration panel.

Reports -> Products -> Products Ordered  gives me the day the product was sold and how many orders contain it, but I need to know which specific orders include the product.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of orders in magento extension that have a certain product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125638/get-a-list-of-orders-in-magento-extension-that-have-a-certain-product)

Comment: maybe you should change the accepted the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get by simple mysql query:-

```
select order_id from sales_flat_order_item where product_id=//given product id
```

OR

You can customize the reports according to your needs.

Comment: Yup, that's almost what I had tried. My error was, since I had the product's name instead of the product_id, to look for the product's name in the "description" field instead of the "name" field.

Comment: How would this work if magento is set to not use flat tables?

Comment: @Benubird the decision of using flat tables or not only affects the catalog, orders always use flat tables (at least since an early version of Magento, maybe 1.2)

Comment: In Magento, direct database queries should always be avoided! Look at the solution I provided below...

Answer (score 26):

I answered this question in another question;
[Get a list of orders in magento extension that have a certain product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125638/get-a-list-of-orders-in-magento-extension-that-have-a-certain-product/18126579#18126579)

For quick reference:

```
$productId = {PRODUCT_ID};
$orders = array();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId))
    ->load();
foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
    $orders[$orderItem->getOrder()->getIncrementId()] = $orderItem->getOrder();
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer IMO... You should not query direct to the database, this is a much better and elegant solution.

Comment: Even if it was the chosen correct answer, it would have been better to have flagged this question as a duplicate rather than answering this one.

Comment: @Coulton a bit after the punch, but at the time, I could not flag... Hence this way

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the increment_id (the incremental Order Number) instead of the order_id, you can simply use this Statement:

```
SELECT o.increment_id 
FROM sales_flat_order_item oi 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o ON o.entity_id = oi.order_id 
WHERE product_id=XXX ORDER BY o.increment_id DESC;
```

Comment: Even though this is a year later, I must say this is the more useful code in this question and I find myself coming back to it every couple of weeks as a reference. Thanks.